Path working in scss file, but not in html template
I have the compilerOptions.paths in my tsconfig.json file set up as such:
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/" : ["src/"],
      "@/*" : ["src/*"],
      "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
      "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"]
    }

I'm working in an Angular 18 project. In my home.component.scss file I have the following lines:
.main-callout {
    background: url('@/assets/img/bg.jpg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 646px;
}

The background image appears normally here. When I go to my navbar.component.html and use the following code:
    <a class="navbar-brand fs-1" href="#">
        <img src="@/assets/icons/Asset 1@2x.png" />
    </a>

the image is not found.
I found a similar issue that someone was having in vuejs and this is where I got some of my solution, but it didn't work for me
https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/589
Shouldn't the paths be recognized across the application once everything is compiled?

is there a way in angular to make it so I don't have ../../../.. etc... in all my image references in the html?

In your templates you should be able to just use a relative path to your image without any prefix. <img src="assets/my-image.png"> Is this an acceptable solution for you?

that is an acceptable solution for me!

You can simply use a path without any prefix:
<img src="assets/my-image.png">

Or depending on how your base URL is set up, you might need to add a leading slash:
<img src="/assets/my-image.png">

But it shouldn't be necessary to use relative paths for assets.

The paths we set up in tsconfig.json are mainly for helping TypeScript understand where your files are. This works in your TypeScript code and, in some cases your SCSS, It is because of how Angular or Webpack might be configured (nothing for html).
because of that for the image source in your navbar, Angular doesn’t know how to resolve that.
The build process doesn’t translate those custom aliases in HTML files.
so what you can do is one of these two options:


<!-- Relative Paths-->

<img src="../../assets/my-image.png" />

<!-- OR -->

<!-- Absolute Paths-->
<img src="assets/my-image.png" />



